# How to turn slides of Power Point into .jpg pics?

Tags: powerpoint

How to turn slides of Power Point into .jpg pics? Is there any such function in ppt? If yes, how can I get to it? Perhaps, not .jpg, but I need to turn slides into pictures. How can I do that?

Comment: This looks like something for [su].

Comment: Ooops! Sorry! Can anyone move it there, please?

Comment: I flagged it for migration, so wait a bit and see if it's migrated.

Comment: File > Save As > JPG, At least in 2013...Found it on a few Google search results too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the PowerPoint, go to Save As and choose Other Formats. In the Save as type, choose JPG. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a program such as http://www.picpick.org/en/ to take screenshots of your slides.